# Please solve this error "An error occurred while initializing the YouTube player."

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have an android app, which allows to play YouTube video. I am using the latest YouTube API v3. I try it on a several devices within android version 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10, 11 and it works perfect (on every device is YouTube app version 16. But on one device, where is android 11 and YouTube app updated version 18.22.36 it does not work and get an error "An error occurred while initializing YouTube player". So I don't know, where is the problem?

I already used

```xml
<queries>
   <intent>
      <action android:name="com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START" />
   </intent>
</queries>
```

Does somebody have an idea, what is wrong or how can I fix it?

Thanks a lot.